Deploying Django project with Nginx, uWSGI and docker
I am trying to deploy and run a django application by using uWSGI, Nginx and docker on DigitalOcean. The Nginx and uWSGI works fine (I think) but I do not know why the uWSGI do not recieve any requests from Nginx.
Here is my nginx configuration
# upstream for uWSGI
upstream uwsgi_app {
    server unix:/tmp/uwsgi/my_project.sock;
}

# upstream for Daphne
upstream daphne {
    server unix:/tmp/uwsgi/my_project_daphne.sock;
}

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name www.domaine.com domaine.com;
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen               443 ssl;
    ssl_certificate      /code/django_project/ssl/certs/cert.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key  /code/django_project/ssl/certs/key.pem
    server_name  www.domaine.com domaine.com;
    error_log    stderr warn;
    access_log   /dev/stdout main;

    location / {
        include      /etc/nginx/uwsgi_params;
        uwsgi_pass   uwsgi_app;
    }

    location /ws/ {
        proxy_http_version  1.1;
        proxy_set_header    Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header    Connection "upgrade";
        proxy_redirect      off;
        proxy_pass          http://daphne;
    }

    location /static/ {
        alias /code/django_project/staticfiles/;
    }
    location /media/ {
        alias /code/django_project/mediafiles/;
    }
}


my uWSGI file
[uwsgi]

socket       = /tmp/uwsgi/my_project.sock
chdir        = /code/django_project/

module       = django_project.wsgi:application
master       = true
processes    = 2

chmod-socket = 666
uid          = www-data
gid          = www-data

harakiri     = 60
vacuum       = true
buffer-size  = 32768

logger       = file:/tmp/uwsgi.log
log-maxsize  = 200000

**My Dockerfile **
FROM python:3.11.5


### 3. Set environment variables
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1
ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE 1


RUN mkdir /code
COPY . /code/
WORKDIR /code

RUN chmod +x /code/wait-for-it.sh


# uwsgi setup
RUN apk add python3-dev build-base linux-headers pcre-dev

RUN set -e;\
    /usr/local/bin/python -m pip install --upgrade pip ;\
    python -m pip install --default-timeout=100 -r /code/requirements/deploy.txt ;


CMD ["uwsgi", "--ini", "/code/config/uwsgi/uwsgi.ini"]

My docker-compose.yml file :
services:

app:
    image: "${APP_IMAGE}"
    restart: unless-stopped
    command: >
      bash -c "./wait-for-it.sh db:5432 --
      && uwsgi --ini /code/config/uwsgi/uwsgi.ini
      && python /code/django_project/manage.py makemigrations
      && python /code/django_project/manage.py migrate"
    volumes:
      - .:/code
      - /var/log/django_project:/code/logs
      - uwsgi_data:/tmp/uwsgi/
    environment:
      - DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=django_project.settings.test
      - POSTGRES_USER=${USER_DB}
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=${PASSWORD_DB}
      - POSTGRES_DB=${DB_NAME}
      - POSTGRES_PORT= ${PORT_DB}
    env_file:
      - .env
    networks:
      - django_project_network
    container_name: app


nginx:
    container_name: nginx
    restart: unless-stopped
    image: "${NGINX_IMAGE}"
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
    volumes:
      - uwsgi_data:/tmp/uwsgi/
    command: "/bin/sh -c 'while :; do sleep 6h & wait $${!}; nginx -s reload; done & nginx -g \"daemon off;\"'"
    networks:
      - django_project_network
    depends_on:
      - app

volumes:
  uwsgi_data:

networks:
    django_project_network:
        driver: bridge

In the logs, of docker, that is what I get for app :
[uWSGI] getting INI configuration from /code/config/uwsgi/uwsgi.ini
wait-for-it.sh: waiting 15 seconds for db:5432
wait-for-it.sh: db:5432 is available after 0 seconds
[uWSGI] getting INI configuration from /code/config/uwsgi/uwsgi.ini
wait-for-it.sh: waiting 15 seconds for db:5432
wait-for-it.sh: db:5432 is available after 0 seconds
[uWSGI] getting INI configuration from /code/config/uwsgi/uwsgi.ini
wait-for-it.sh: waiting 15 seconds for db:5432
wait-for-it.sh: db:5432 is available after 0 seconds
[uWSGI] getting INI configuration from /code/config/uwsgi/uwsgi.ini
wait-for-it.sh: waiting 15 seconds for db:5432
wait-for-it.sh: db:5432 is available after 0 seconds
[uWSGI] getting INI configuration from /code/config/uwsgi/uwsgi.ini

2024/06/15 17:32:58 [notice] 9#9: using the "epoll" event method
2024/06/15 17:32:58 [notice] 9#9: nginx/1.23.1
2024/06/15 17:32:58 [notice] 9#9: built by gcc 10.2.1 20210110 (Debian 10.2.1-6)
2024/06/15 17:32:58 [notice] 9#9: OS: Linux 5.15.0-112-generic
2024/06/15 17:32:58 [notice] 9#9: getrlimit(RLIMIT_NOFILE): 1048576:1048576
2024/06/15 17:32:58 [notice] 9#9: start worker processes
2024/06/15 17:32:58 [notice] 9#9: start worker process 10
# 2024/06/15 17:34:28 [error] 10#10: *1 open() "/usr/share/nginx/html/index.php" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 94.73.145.234, server: localhost, request: "GET /index.php?route=extension/module/update/cevap HTTP/1.0", host: "domaine.com"
94.73.145.234 - - [15/Jun/2024:17:34:28 +0000] "GET /index.php?route=extension/module/update/cevap HTTP/1.0" 404 153 "-" "-" "-"
2024/06/15 17:40:08 [error] 10#10: *7 open() "/usr/share/nginx/html/wp-content/plugins/hellopress/wp_filemanager.php" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 52.169.254.120, server: localhost, request: "GET /wp-content/plugins/hellopress/wp_filemanager.php HTTP/1.1", host: "domaine.com"
52.169.254.120 - - [15/Jun/2024:17:40:08 +0000] "GET /wp-content/plugins/hellopress/wp_filemanager.php HTTP/1.1" 404 153 "-" "-" "-"
2024/06/15 17:40:08 [error] 10#10: *7 open() "/usr/share/nginx/html/lv.php" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 52.169.254.120, server: localhost, request: "GET /lv.php HTTP/1.1", host: "domaine.com"
52.169.254.120 - - [15/Jun/2024:17:40:08 +0000] "GET /lv.php HTTP/1.1" 404 153 "-" "-" "-"
2024/06/15 17:40:09 [error] 10#10: *7 open() "/usr/share/nginx/html/wp-22.php" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 52.169.254.120, server: localhost, request: "GET /wp-22.php?sfilename=bdkr28tools.php&sfilecontent=&supfiles= HTTP/1.1", host: "domaine.com"
52.169.254.120 - - [15/Jun/2024:17:40:09 +0000] "GET /wp-22.php?sfilename=bdkr28tools.php&sfilecontent=&supfiles= HTTP/1.1" 404 153 "-" "-" "-"
2024/06/15 17:40:09 [error] 10#10: *7 open() "/usr/share/nginx/html/wp-content/plugins/pwnd/pwnd.php" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 52.169.254.120, server: localhost, request: "GET /wp-content/plugins/pwnd/pwnd.php HTTP/1.1", host: "domaine.com"
52.169.254.120 - - [15/Jun/2024:17:40:09 +0000] "GET /wp-content/plugins/pwnd/pwnd.php HTTP/1.1" 404 153 "-" "-" "-"

Please can you help me to figure out how to make it work together ? I think that is the main problem. I really need your help. Any answer is welcome. Thanks for advance :)
I try to read the uwsgi docs and some youtube vidoes but nothing works for me.
